# Instant app openGL rendering only on Android Pie 9.0.0

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, android-instant-apps

I have published an instant app, which can be downloaded from **android marshmallow, nougat, etc.** but openGL is only being rendered on android pie, the normal app works fine on all android versions, both APK's are the same actually it is an app bundle.

Comment: Do you have any logs you can share?
Otherwise, please file this issue to Google @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 They will be able to investigate if you can provide logs and a sample project.

Answer (score 0):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132952558

Quoting the answer here so it helps others as well:

> OpenGL ES 1.0 is only partially supported, we do not recommend you to
> use this.
>
> OpenGL ES 2.0 is fully supported for Instant Apps.
>
> Additionally, OpenGL ES 3.0 is not supported on pre-O Instant Apps.
>
> This was previously documented somewhere, but not anymore, so we’re
> working on getting these details back in.